# column ambiguously defined oracle error

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this code, every time I get "column ambiguously defined". Can not solve this. I can't understand that error cause.

```
SELECT dc.name, COUNT(am.idn), adm.count 
FROM vpdgk.vp_admin am 
    INNER JOIN vpdgk.vp_mufettish mf ON am.mufet_id = mf.IDN
    INNER JOIN dictionaries.customs_main dc ON dc.code_int = mf.FIRM
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT C.MUFET_ID, d.name name, b.name, COUNT(c.MUFET_ID) count
            FROM vpdgk.vp_qeydiyyat A
                INNER JOIN vpdgk.vp_mufettish b ON b.IDN = A.mufet_id 
                INNER JOIN vpdgk.vp_admin c ON c.mufet_id = A.mufet_id 
                        AND (c.uid_ is not null or c.uid_reserv is not null)
                INNER JOIN dictionaries.customs_main d ON d.code_int = b.FIRM
            WHERE TRUNC(A.INSERT_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') 
                       AND TO_DATE('30.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY')
            GROUP BY C.MUFET_ID, d.name, b.name
            Having COUNT(c.MUFET_ID) < 10) adm
        ON dc.name = adm.name
GROUP BY dc.name, adm.count;
```

Comment: This site accepts questions in English only.

Comment: Google translate tells me your question is: `Who can help me, please. When I run this code, every time I get "column is not unique." I can not solve this, even I can not understand what is causing the error. please, please, please help. I could not work it out for a long time :(` If that is a fair translation, please update your question. :)

Comment: i mean "Can anyone help me please. When i run this code, everytime i get "column ambiguously defined". Can not solve this even i can understand that error cause. please, please, please help. I could not solve it out for a long time :( "

Comment: Within the `adm` subselect, you have two columns defined with the name - `name`. Resolve that issue and then re-test.

Comment: Just like **mjsqu** said, you have two columns with aliases `name` in your `adm` subquery.
Also, it's not the best idea to name the aliases with key words (like `COUNT`).

Comment: @Afa I edited the formatting of your code, not the code itself. The formatting makes it easier to spot the problem.

Comment: thank you for your answers @mjsqu . i have a question.i just named d.name column with alias "name" , the other one is not alias, just b.name . can it cause a problem?please answer

Comment: thank you so much @AndrewMcCoist .  i have a question.i just named d.name column with alias "name" , the other one is not alias, just b.name . can it cause a problem?please answer

Comment: Well, this should actually work, but you'd better just change your aliases so they should be meaningfull - e.g. `dict_name` and `muffetish_name`.
It'll be easier to understand for you, when you read the code after a while (sometimes weeks, sometimes months or even years later).

Comment: thank you so much @EdCottrell

Comment: thank you for your answer with explanation :) @AndrewMcCoist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT C.MUFET_ID, d.name name, b.name, COUNT(c.MUFET_ID) count
...
```

You have the column name `name` defined twice. Change one of them. Also change it in the `Group By`.

Comment: thank you so much @steenbergh. i have a question.i just named d.name column with alias "name" , the other one is not alias, just b.name . can it cause a problem?please answer

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. Are the names the same? Then why select them both? If not the same, find a better - more descriptive - alias for one (or both) of these columns.

Comment: thank you so so much for answer. i got it :) @steenbergh